# Picker within Custom Control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I am building up a few forms (using `TableView`) and noticed that I was styling the cells the same. I decided that I would refactor this repeated code into a common control.

I am struggling to get the binding to work on the picker correctly. My custom control looks like this:[image: picture of the cell]

My control is a `ViewCell`, so that I can display it within a `TableView`:

```
public partial class PickerCell : ViewCell
{
...
}
```

I have been able to set the pickers `ItemSource`, but I cannot get the `SelectedItem` or `DisplayItemBinding` properties to work.

I've seen [this post from 2015](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37933/bindable-picker-in-a-cell) (ancient now) but I tried and the methods were marked as obsolete and didn't work anyway.

I've also tried in the controls ctor:

```
ItemPicker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, "ItemSource");
ItemPicker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "SelectedItem", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

but that didn't work either.

I basically just want to add a way so that I can bind to the picker from my xaml to the control. I really hope this is possible because I use this exact view cell around my application maybe 9/10 times. I really don't to be repeating myself alot and I'd normally create controls in this scenario. For instance I have a similarly styled cell for entries and that works perfectly....

Here is the code I used to set the item source:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(ItemsSource),
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(PickerCell)
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((PickerCell) bindable).OnItemsSourceChanged((IList) newVal)
);

public IList ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IList list)
{
    ItemPicker.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

I tried to implement some of the code for picker [from Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Picker.cs) but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation of a custom picker cell. The only change to vanilla xamarin is that the binding display must be input as a `string` instead of `binding: property`.

Here is all the important code:

**Bindable Property Declarations**

```
/// <summary>
/// The placeholder property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Placeholder),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(CustomPickerCell),
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((CustomPickerCell)bindable).OnPlaceholderChanged((string)newVal)
);

/// <summary>
/// The items source property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(ItemsSource),
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(CustomPickerCell),
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((CustomPickerCell)bindable).OnItemsSourceChanged((IList)newVal)
);

/// <summary>
/// The selected item property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(SelectedItem),
    typeof(object),
    typeof(CustomPickerCell),
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((CustomPickerCell)bindable).OnSelectedItemChanged((object)newVal)
);

/// <summary>
/// The item display binding property
/// NOTE: Use the name of the property, you do not need to bind to this property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDisplayBindingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(ItemDisplayBinding),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(CustomPickerCell),
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((CustomPickerCell)bindable).OnItemDisplayBindingChanged((string)newVal)
);
```

**Bindable Properties**

```
/// <summary>
/// The cell's placeholder (select a ....).
/// </summary>
/// <value>The placeholder.</value>
public string Placeholder
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// The cell's picker item source.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The items source.</value>
public IList ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the selected item.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The selected item.</value>
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the item display binding.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The item display binding.</value>
public string ItemDisplayBinding
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ItemDisplayBindingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemDisplayBindingProperty, value); }
}
```

**Property Changed Methods**

```
/// <summary>
/// Called when PlaceholderProperty changes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newVal">New value.</param>
private void OnPlaceholderChanged(string newVal)
{
    ItemPicker.Title = newVal;
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when ItemSourceProperty changes.
/// </summary>
private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IList list)
{
    ItemPicker.ItemsSource = list;
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when SelectedItemProperty changes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">Object.</param>
private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object obj)
{
    ItemPicker.SelectedItem = obj;
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when ItemDisplayBindingProperty changes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newvalue">Newvalue.</param>
private void OnItemDisplayBindingChanged(string newvalue)
{
    ItemPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding(newvalue);
}
```

**Initialisation**

```
public CustomPickerCell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ItemPicker.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;
    ItemPicker.SelectedItem = this.SelectedItem;

    ItemPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// Calle when ItemPicker's SelectedIndexChanged event fires.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
/// <param name="e">E.</param>
void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedItem = (ItemPicker.SelectedIndex < 0 || ItemPicker.SelectedIndex > ItemPicker.Items.Count - 1) ? null : ItemsSource[ItemPicker.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Now all you need to do is add this cell to your xaml and you are good to go!

**Usage**

```
<!-- Where controls is a namespace defined in your xaml -->
<!-- Not not to bind ItemDisplayBinding, you only need the property name as a string-->
<controls:CustomPickerCell Title="Type" Placeholder="Select an ice cream" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding IceCreamList}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIceCream, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        ItemDisplayBinding="Name"/>
```

Comment: `ItemDisplayBinding="Name"` solved it for me! It being a string instead of a path to the property of the object was really key for me, thanks. I was using `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Source={...}, Path=Name}"` and it was trying to get the `Name` property out of my view model, instead of the object from the `ObservableCollection` assigned to `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation for my custom picker where I wanted to implement an event handler for when the selected item changed. Below is how I did it.

In your custom picker's code-behind, implement an `EventHandler` property and private variable:

```
private EventHandler onIndexChanged = null;
...
public event EventHandler OnIndexChangedEvent
{
    add
    {
        onIndexChanged = null;
        onIndexChanged = value;
    }
    remove
    {
        onIndexChanged = null;
    }
}
```

In your custom picker's XAML, add a handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` property:

```xml
<Picker
    x:Name="MyPicker"
    SelectedIndexChanged="Handle_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Then back in your code-behind, implement this handler:

```cs
void Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Trigger the implemented event, if not null.
    onIndexChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

The above isn't bindable, so to implement this, you have to:

1. Set the handler in your main view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="MyApp.MyPage"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <controls:CustomPicker
                ItemSource="{Binding SelectionList}"
                OnIndexChangedEvent="Handle_PickerIndexChangedEvent"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

2. Implement the handler in your view's code-behind to call your view model's handler:

```cs
private void Handle_PickerIndexChangedEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.HandlerIndexChanged(); // or whatever
}
```

There are probably better ways to do this, namely implementing `Command` and `CommandParameter`. However, the above worked for me, even if I had to bend the MVVM rules a bit.

Comment: The picker's selected item property is bindable and will fire the event's you are looking for. My case is more stitching the pickers main functionality (item source, display binding & selected item) to a separate control (view / cell / etc). I'm also not looking to bend MVVM since the reason I'm refactoring my code to this format is to better adhere to MVVM!

Comment: I forgot to actually show the XAML implementation. Added it now. Were you not looking for a way to attach an external handler to your `Picker`'s index changed event?

Comment: No I was looking for a way to embed a picker in a separate control. My scenario is that I have a form with a lot of pickers on it, the UI is the same so I made a custom `ViewCell` called `PickerCell`. This control can bind Title, Placeholder & To the pickers. I'm currently at the stage of head into brick wall where I've got the `ItemSource` and `SelectedItem` binding correctly. I've just got the `ItemDisplayBinding` to go!