# Display property binding works in code but not xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have inherited some code that has a custom picker control. The control is configured in the code-behind with a `List<TrialSource>` and sets the display property via:

```cs
TrialSource.FieldToDisplay = new Xamarin.Forms.Binding("DisplayName");
```

If instead I move that to the XAML, the property isn't set and I just get the type as the display text.

```
FieldToDisplay="{Binding DisplayName}"
```

With the debugger I can trace the execution through the custom control and the code behind version triggers the `FieldToDisplayChanged()` event. The XAML version doesn't. What am I missing? Custom picker control code:

```cs
public BindingBase FieldToDisplay
{
    get => (BindingBase)GetValue(FieldToDisplayProperty);
    set => SetValue(FieldToDisplayProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty FieldToDisplayProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FieldToDisplay), typeof(BindingBase), typeof(PickerField),
        propertyChanged: FieldToDisplayChanged);

private static void FieldToDisplayChanged(BindableObject bindable, object value, object newValue)
{
    var matEntry = (PickerField)bindable;
    matEntry.SelectField.ItemDisplayBinding = (BindingBase)newValue;
}
```

Comment: "custom picker control" - without knowing more about this "custom" control its hard to say

Comment: Because with xaml binding you are obviously getting value of `DisplayName` property of DataContext(which prolly doesn't not exists, so there is no data change) **not `BindingBase` derived class instance**

Comment: Is there anyway to resolve that in the XAML binding or do I just have to live with it if I don't want to modify the custom picker code?

Comment: Static string resource and custom value converter... But I would rather change FieldToDisplay to string. Then you could create new binding based on this string inside FieldToDisplayChanged

Comment: Thanks @Selvin that's pretty much what I expected but good to have it spelled out.

Comment: Resolved using reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55407567/132599

Comment: This could be an issue with your Binding Context. The control might not be aware of what it should be Binding to. Maybe try set the BindingContext property in your xaml

Comment: Thanks @Janwilx72 the binding context is fine, it was the code to bind the `DisplayName` property that need to be a string and not `BindingBase`-derived.